# Как заменить ключи массива которые хранятся в другом массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Как заменить ключи массива на другие ключи из другого массива?
Мы имеем изначально примерно вот такой вот массив, это может быть список товаров, статей и т.д.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [A] => Name item
        [B] => 250
        [C] => 340
        [D] => 280
        [E] => 246
        [F] => 336
        [G] => 226
        [H] => 1
        [I] => 12
        [J] => 19
        [K] => Class
        [L] => 137
        [M] => 136.73
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [A] => Name item
        [B] => 250
        [C] => 340
        [D] => 280
        [E] => 246
        [F] => 336
        [G] => 226
        [H] => 1
        [I] => 12
        [J] => 19
        [K] => Class
        [L] => 300
        [M] => 136.73
        [N] => 163.35
    )
```

И массив где хранятся нужные нам ключи

```
    Array
(
    [Model] => A
    [Height] => B
    [Width] => C
    [Depth] => D
    [InnerHeight] => E
    [InnerWidth] => F
    [InnerDepth] => G
    [Shelves] => H
    [Weight] => I
    [Volume] => J
    [Class] => K
    [Price] => L
)
```

Чтобы вышло так

```
[0] => Array
(
    [Model] => Name item
    [Height] => 250
    [Width] => 340
    [Depth] => 280
    [InnerHeight] => 246
    [InnerWidth] => 336
    [InnerDepth] => 226
    [Shelves] => 1
    [Weight] => 12
    [Volume] => 19
    [Class] => Class
    [Price] => 137
    [M] => 136.73
)
```

И как вы заметили есть последний элемент M, его нужно убрать.
Мне в голову приходит использовать цикл for в foreach, но не до конца догоняю структуру выполнения задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно пройти по массиву циклом *(или подходящей php-функцией)*, на каждой итерации удаляя последний элемент. После этого сгенерировать новый массив с помощью `array_combine()`, передавая первым аргументом ключи второго массива *(которые были получены с помощью `array_keys()`)*, а вторым - значения исходного массива:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'A' => 'Name item',
        'B' => 250,
        'C' => 340,
        'D' => 280,
        'E' => 246,
        'F' => 336,
        'G' => 226,
        'H' => 1,
        'I' => 12,
        'J' => 19,
        'K' => 'Class',
        'L' => 137,
        'M' => '136.73'
    ),
    array(
        'A' => 'Name item',
        'B' => 250,
        'C' => 340,
        'D' => 280,
        'E' => 246,
        'F' => 336,
        'G' => 226,
        'H' => 1,
        'I' => 12,
        'J' => 19,
        'K' => 'Class',
        'L' => 137,
        'M' => '136.73',
        'N' => '163.35'
    )
);

$keys = array(
    'Model' => 'A',
    'Height' => 'B',
    'Width' => 'C',
    'Depth' => 'D',
    'InnerHeight' => 'E',
    'InnerWidth' => 'F',
    'InnerDepth' => 'G',
    'Shelves' => 'H',
    'Weight' => 'I',
    'Volume' => 'J',
    'Class' => 'K',
    'Price' => 'L',
    'M' => '136.73'
);

$array = array_map(function($arr) use($keys) {
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 0, count($keys));
    return array_combine(array_keys($keys), $arr);
}, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=13)
      'Model' => string 'Name item' (length=9)
      'Height' => int 250
      'Width' => int 340
      'Depth' => int 280
      'InnerHeight' => int 246
      'InnerWidth' => int 336
      'InnerDepth' => int 226
      'Shelves' => int 1
      'Weight' => int 12
      'Volume' => int 19
      'Class' => string 'Class' (length=5)
      'Price' => int 137
      'M' => string '136.73' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=13)
      'Model' => string 'Name item' (length=9)
      'Height' => int 250
      'Width' => int 340
      'Depth' => int 280
      'InnerHeight' => int 246
      'InnerWidth' => int 336
      'InnerDepth' => int 226
      'Shelves' => int 1
      'Weight' => int 12
      'Volume' => int 19
      'Class' => string 'Class' (length=5)
      'Price' => int 137
      'M' => string '136.73' (length=6)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо... я думал надо целый функционал писать...

Comment: @Solunski.D подправил ответ с учётом того, что в исходном массиве может быть больше элементов, чем в массиве с ключами.

Comment: Большое спасибо, 3 года занимаюсь сайтами, а в php не силен(

Comment: @Solunski.D читайте мануал, и будете разбираться лучше :) Там все функции можно найти для любых задач. Главное, понимать логику их использования.